# Plot specific area of map

Tags: cartography, r

Is there a way to zoom in a map on an R spatial polygons object.

i.e. if I have polygons for a whole country but I want to zoom in on a specific city and just plot that area how do I do that ?

At the moment I am just plotting a chloropleth of the whole country like this:

```
    colours<-(brewer.pal(9, "YlGn"))
    brks<-classIntervals(poly$var1, n=9, style="quantile")
    brks<-brks$brks
    plot(ED, col=colours[findInterval(poly$var1, brks,all.inside=TRUE)], axes=F, border=FALSE)
```

I wanna zoom in and plot a rectangular area around a particular city but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xlim` and `ylim` args to plot:

```
require(spdep) # for sample data 
data(columbus)
plot(columbus)
axis(1);axis(2) # see where we are
plot(columbus,xlim=c(8,9),ylim=c(12,13))
```

OR if you don't know the coords get them using `locator`:

```
plot(columbus)
xy=locator(2,"p") # click two corners
plot(columbus,xlim=xy$x,ylim=xy$y)
```

OR use `zoom` from the `raster` package:

```
require(raster)
plot(columbus)
zoom(columbus) # click corners
```

Comment: Thanks!I also had the idea to subset the map using a larger scale area code - but that would not be nice and rectangular so I look your solution better!